# How do you optimize this code for nn prediction?

Tags: python, performance, numpy, scipy, nearest-neighbor

How do you optimize this code?
At the moment it is running to slow for the amount of data that goes through this loop. This code runs 1-nearest neighbor. It will predict the label of the training_element based off the p_data_set

```
#               [x] ,           [[x1],[x2],[x3]],    [l1, l2, l3]
def prediction(training_element, p_data_set, p_label_set):
    temp = np.array([], dtype=float)
    for p in p_data_set:
        temp = np.append(temp, distance.euclidean(training_element, p))

    minIndex = np.argmin(temp)
    return p_label_set[minIndex]
```

Comment: What are the shapes of the inputs involved?

Comment: (100L), (40,000, 100L) , (40,000)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [*k*-D tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree) for fast nearest-neighbour lookups, e.g. [`scipy.spatial.cKDTree`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.cKDTree.html):

```
from scipy.spatial import cKDTree

# I assume that p_data_set is (nsamples, ndims)
tree = cKDTree(p_data_set)

# training_elements is also assumed to be (nsamples, ndims)
dist, idx = tree.query(training_elements, k=1)

predicted_labels = p_label_set[idx]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`distance.cdist`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html#scipy.spatial.distance.cdist) to directly get the distances `temp` and then use `.argmin()` to get min-index, like so -

```
minIndex = distance.cdist(training_element[None],p_data_set).argmin()
```

Here's an alternative approach using [`np.einsum`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.4/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) -

```
subs = p_data_set - training_element
minIndex =  np.einsum('ij,ij->i',subs,subs).argmin()
```

**Runtime test**

Well I was thinking `cKDTree` would easily beat `cdist`, but I guess `training_element` being a `1D` array isn't too heavy for `cdist` and I am seeing it to beat out `cKDTree` instead by a good **`10x+`** margin!

Here's the timing results -

```
In [422]: # Setup arrays
     ...: p_data_set = np.random.randint(0,9,(40000,100))
     ...: training_element = np.random.randint(0,9,(100,))
     ...: 

In [423]: def tree_based(p_data_set,training_element): #@ali_m's soln
     ...:     tree = cKDTree(p_data_set)
     ...:     dist, idx = tree.query(training_element, k=1)
     ...:     return idx
     ...: 
     ...: def einsum_based(p_data_set,training_element):    
     ...:     subs = p_data_set - training_element
     ...:     return np.einsum('ij,ij->i',subs,subs).argmin()
     ...: 

In [424]: %timeit tree_based(p_data_set,training_element)
1 loops, best of 3: 210 ms per loop

In [425]: %timeit einsum_based(p_data_set,training_element)
100 loops, best of 3: 17.3 ms per loop

In [426]: %timeit distance.cdist(training_element[None],p_data_set).argmin()
100 loops, best of 3: 14.8 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 0):

Python can be quite fast programming language if used properly.
This is my suggestion (faster_prediction):

```
import numpy as np
import time

def euclidean(a,b):
    return np.linalg.norm(a-b)

def prediction(training_element, p_data_set, p_label_set):
    temp = np.array([], dtype=float)
    for p in p_data_set:
        temp = np.append(temp, euclidean(training_element, p))

    minIndex = np.argmin(temp)
    return p_label_set[minIndex]

def faster_prediction(training_element, p_data_set, p_label_set):    
    temp = np.tile(training_element, (p_data_set.shape[0],1))
    temp = np.sqrt(np.sum( (temp - p_data_set)**2 , 1))    

    minIndex = np.argmin(temp)
    return p_label_set[minIndex]   


training_element = [1,2,3]
p_data_set = np.random.rand(100000, 3)*10
p_label_set = np.r_[0:p_data_set.shape[0]]


t1 = time.time()
result_1 = prediction(training_element, p_data_set, p_label_set)
t2 = time.time()

t3 = time.time()
result_2 = faster_prediction(training_element, p_data_set, p_label_set)
t4 = time.time()


print "Execution time 1:", t2-t1, "value: ", result_1
print "Execution time 2:", t4-t3, "value: ", result_2
print "Speed up: ", (t4-t3) / (t2-t1)
```

I get the following result on pretty old laptop:

```
Execution time 1: 21.6033108234 value:  9819
Execution time 2: 0.0176379680634 value:  9819
Speed up:  1224.81857013
```

which makes me think I must have done some stupid mistake :)

In case of very huge data, where memory might be an issue, I suggest using Cython or implementing function in C++ and wrapping it in python.

Comment: if many searches are required with the same data set, I would recommend KDTree, as described above by ali_m.